# Increase spacing in split environment

Tags: equations, spacing, amsmath

I'm writing long equations with the split environment:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
...
\\
...
\\
...
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The problem is that the single lines are a bit high, and there is too little vertical spacing, so that the result looks messy.

Is there a way to increase the vertical space of the split environment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The length `\jot` determines the space in a multi-line amsmath enironment. You could adjust it, affecting all lines or use the optional argument of `\\` to increase the spacing specifically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setlength{\jot}{10pt} % affecting the line spacing in the environment
\begin{split}
1
\\
2
\\[3ex]% additional space affecting just this line
3
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Changing `\jot` inside the outer equation environment limits the scope of this action.

But as it seems that you just want to adjust certain lines, using `\\` at this point should be sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

The traditional way is

```
\begin{equation}
\openup 1\jot
\begin{split}
...
\\
...
\\
...
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

**Edit**: From the definition in ltmath.dtx (which is copied directly from plain tex)

```
\def\openup{\afterassignment\@penup\dimen@}
\def\@penup{\advance\lineskip\dimen@
   \advance\baselineskip\dimen@
   \advance\lineskiplimit\dimen@}
```

Ie, `\openup dimen` just increases the line spacing by dimen. Traditionally, `dimen` is given in units of `\jot`, which often set to 3 pt. It's all described in the TeXBook.

Comment: Wow, what trickery is that?!?