# How to increase the spacing between equations in "gather"?

Tags: equations, spacing, amsmath

Is there a way to consistently increase the vertical spacing between equation lines in a `gather` (or `gather*`) environment from `amsmath`?

Specifically, I want to produce something like

```
\begin{gather*}
a = b \\[2ex]
c = d \\[2ex]
e = f
\end{gather*}
```

without having to write `[2ex]` at the end of each equation line.

I can think of some hacks that redefine `\\` to automatically add the spacing, but is there some cleaner/better way to achieve this?

Comment: See also [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/increase-spacing-in-split-environment).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This can be achieved by increasing the length `\jot` which amsmath uses between lines in multi-line formulas. Either write

```
\setlength{\jot}{value}
```

or

```
\addtolength{\jot}{value}
```

to increase the spacing. It's very similar to [Increase spacing in split environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/increase-spacing-in-split-environment), since it's the same technique though another environment is meant.

Comment: This assigment of \jot works only inside document text but not in preambule. How can I do this inside some my sty-package or, at least in a preambule?

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're after, but the [mathtools](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/mathtools.html) manual mentions, in relation to a new environment it provides, that the distance between lines in `gather` and other multiline environments is set by a dimension called `\jot`. By changing this length, e.g. `\setlength{\jot}{2ex}`, you can set it for the entire document.

Said environment is called `spreadlines` by the way, and changes this setting locally. This example is copied from the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads and extends amsmath
\begin{document}    
\begin{spreadlines}{20pt}  
Large spaces between the lines.  
\begin{gather}  
a=b\\  
c=d  
\end{gather}  
\end{spreadlines}  
Back to normal spacing.
\begin{gather}  
a=b\\    
c=d   
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way (inherited from plain tex) is to do

```
\openup 2ex
\begin{gather*}
a = b \\
c = d \\
e = f
\end{gather*}
```

Although it's more traditional to use units of `\jot` rather than `ex`.