# How do I space out the lines in my gather block?

Tags: math-mode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increase the spacing between equations in “gather”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2929/how-to-increase-the-spacing-between-equations-in-gather)

This Tex snippet produces the crowded output below.

```
\begin{gather}
\frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{\frac{7}{2}}{\frac{5!}{3}}
\end{gather}
```

How do I space out the lines so that the fractions are not so close to each other?

[image]

Comment: Add the optional paramter at the end of `\\ ` as in `\\[10pt]` to specify how much vertical space to leave.