# Increase the spacing of rows in equations

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, line-spacing, mathtools

I have a formula and I want to increase the space between the rows to make the reading easier.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{flalign*}
\epsilon \bm{\Xi}_n & = M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1} )  - M(\bm{x}_{n-1})  = \\   &=M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} )  - M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) + M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1})-M^n(\bm{x}) =  \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + M( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-2} ) +\epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-1})  - M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1}) \bm{\xi}_{n-1}+ M^2\left( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} + \epsilon \xibf_{n-2} \right) -M^n(\bm{x})  + O(\epsilon^2) \\
& = \epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1})\bm{\xi}_{n-1}+\epsilon DM^2( \bm{x}_{n-2}) \bm{\xi}_{n-2} + 
M^3( \bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} )-M^n(\bm{x}).
\end{flalign*}
\end{equation}
```

I read this post [Temporarily increase line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48741/temporarily-increase-line-spacing) but there are a lot of different methods. Some of ones works only for text.

I use the following packages:

```
\usepackage{ws-rotating}     
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: flalign inside equation surely generates an error message?

Comment: the use of `\jot` is recommended in answers to this question: [How to increase the spacing between equations in “gather”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2929/579)

Comment: As @barbarabeeton mentions use `\jot`, since your are already mentioning `mathtools`, use the `\begin{spreadlines}{dimen}...\end{spreadlines}` env, `dimen` being a length, say `2em`.

Comment: @daleif -- `em` should always be thought of as a *horizontal* dimension.  for vertical dimensions, better to use `ex`.  and, by the way, `\jot` defaults (in `latex.ltx`) to `3pt`, or (in a `10pt` text environment) a quarter of the usual baseline distance.

Comment: @barbarabeeton that is odd, when it corresponds to the current font *size*. But i agree. I just tend to always use `em` in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to increase row spacing uniformly in a multiline group of equations without having to type `[vertical spacing]` at each line break, you can use `\setstretch` (from the `\setspace` package) at the beginning of such an environment. Btw, if you load `mathtools`, you don't have to load `amsmath`. Also, I think what you need is the `aligned` environment, rather than `flalign*`, which doesn't work with `equation`.

The second example in the example is typeset with `\setstretch{2}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\epsilon \bm{\Xi}_n & = M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1} ) - M(\bm{x}_{n-1}) = \\
&=M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) - M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) + M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1})-M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + M( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-2} ) +\epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-1}) - M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1}) \bm{\xi}_{n-1}+ M^2\left( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} + \epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-2} \right) -M^n(\bm{x}) + O(\epsilon^2) \\
& = \epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1})\bm{\xi}_{n-1}+\epsilon DM^2( \bm{x}_{n-2}) \bm{\xi}_{n-2} +
M^3( \bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} )-M^n(\bm{x}).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{aligned}
\epsilon \bm{\Xi}_n & = M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1} ) - M(\bm{x}_{n-1}) = \\
&=M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) - M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) + M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1})-M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + M( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-2} ) +\epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-1}) - M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1}) \bm{\xi}_{n-1}+ M^2\left( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} + \epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-2} \right) -M^n(\bm{x}) + O(\epsilon^2) \\
& = \epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1})\bm{\xi}_{n-1}+\epsilon DM^2( \bm{x}_{n-2}) \bm{\xi}_{n-2} +
M^3( \bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} )-M^n(\bm{x}).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This adds unwanted space between the last line of text and the first line of the equation. I'm using it with `align*`. Any way to avoid that?

Comment: @Jeff: You can use the `\useshortskip` directive, from `nccmath`, just before the equation, or something like `\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}`.

Answer (score 5):

Just to collaborate on Ians suggestion, here is the same using `spreadlines`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadlines}{1cm}
  \begin{flalign*}
    A &= B \\
    &= C \\
    &= D
  \end{flalign*}
\end{spreadlines}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a length as an optional argument to `\\`. Here I have used `1cm` to exaggerate the effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
A &= B \\[1cm]
  &= C \\[1cm]
  &= D
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image: spacing]

Answer (score 1):

Use the (secret) built-in method:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\epsilon \bm{\Xi}_n & = M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1} ) - M(\bm{x}_{n-1}) = \\
&=M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) - M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) + M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1})-M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + M( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-2} ) +\epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-1}) - M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1}) \bm{\xi}_{n-1}+ M^2\left( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} + \epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-2} \right) -M^n(\bm{x}) + O(\epsilon^2) \\
& = \epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1})\bm{\xi}_{n-1}+\epsilon DM^2( \bm{x}_{n-2}) \bm{\xi}_{n-2} +
M^3( \bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} )-M^n(\bm{x}).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{aligned}
\epsilon \bm{\Xi}_n & = M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1} ) - M(\bm{x}_{n-1}) = \\
&=M_\epsilon(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) - M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-1} ) + M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon,n-1})-M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + M( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-2} ) +\epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-1}) - M^n(\bm{x}) = \\
&=\epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1}) \bm{\xi}_{n-1}+ M^2\left( M(\bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} + \epsilon \bm{\xi}_{n-2} \right) -M^n(\bm{x}) + O(\epsilon^2) \\
& = \epsilon \bm{\xi}_n + \epsilon DM(\bm{x}_{n-1})\bm{\xi}_{n-1}+\epsilon DM^2( \bm{x}_{n-2}) \bm{\xi}_{n-2} +
M^3( \bm{x}_{\epsilon, n-3} )-M^n(\bm{x}).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the trailing equals sign is not necessary; also, I changed your `\left(` and `\right)` into `\bigl(` and `\bigr)` in order to get slightly bigger parentheses.