# How to change the line spacing within an equation environment?

Tags: formatting, equations

[see this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2929/how-to-increase-the-spacing-between-equations-in-gather)

Example;

```
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{aligned}
    1 + 2 = 3 \\[3mm]
    3 + 1 = 4 \\[3mm]
    4 + 1 = 5
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

I find that I'm often adding the `[3mm]` to the ends of equation lines so that the spacing isn't so tight between lines, but is there a way to set this for

- a particular equation instance
- globally for equations

I can't seem to find this out.

## edit

this worked

```
\begin{equation*}
  \addtolength{\jot}{12pt}
  \begin{aligned}
    1 + 2 = 3 \\
    3 + 1 = 4 \\
    4 + 1 = 5
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: [How to increase the spacing between equations in "gather"?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/2931) applies to `aligned` as well, I believe.

Comment: thanks @TorbjørnT. , the only thing that seems to work from there (for me) is the `\openup 2ex`, but it seems to then act on everything after it (even when adding `\openup 0ex` when i want it to cease)

Comment: `spreadlines` and changing `\jot`both worked here.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. sorry it does work - if I put addtolength in the right place! I've updated post - and might delete this if it's duplicate info?

Comment: well i've just said that @TorbjørnT. ?

Comment: No, you said delete. Deleting is not the same as closing.

Comment: ah right I understand sorry... yes closing and having it linked to that post would be better i think, I'm guessing a mod will do this ( I can't see a way to do it from here)

Comment: I've voted to close, so it will likely be closed in a bit. (Needs five votes from users with more than 3000 reputation points or one mod vote.)

Comment: apart from closing, note it's confusing to put an answer in the question, answers should be posted as answers (even if it is the questioner who answers)