# vertical spacing of multlined inside align*

Tags: line-spacing, multline

```
\begin{align*}
    Z &= \begin{multlined}[t]
        \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \tr \bigl\{ Q^{-1} \bigl[ (P_{k+1} + x_{k+1}^N     x_{k+1}^{N\prime}) - (P_{k+1,k}^N + x_{k+1}^N x_k^{N\prime}) A' \\
        - A (P_{k,k+1}^N + x_k^N x_{k+1}^{N\prime}) + A(P_k^N + x_k^N     x_k^{N\prime})A' \bigr] \bigr\}
    \end{multlined} \\
    &= \begin{multlined}[t]
        \tr \bigl\{ Q^{-1} \bigl[ (P_{k+1} + x_{k+1}^N     x_{k+1}^{N\prime}) - (P_{k+1,k}^N + x_{k+1}^N x_k^{N\prime}) A' \\
        - A (P_{k,k+1}^N + x_k^N x_{k+1}^{N\prime}) + A(P_k^N + x_k^N     x_k^{N\prime})A' \bigr] \bigr\}
    \end{multlined}
\end{align*}
```

renders as [image] Obviously the vertical spacing within the second `multlined` environment is too cramped, and if not for the sum providing a buffer the spacing in the first one would be too cramped as well. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can add extra space using `\\[1em]`for example or any other value.

Comment: They are cramped in the same way, but the summation in the first one makes it look like spaced.

Comment: @Sigur -- the `em` is a unit of horizontal space.  better to use a vertical unit.  `\jot`, as cited in an answer this question [How to increase the spacing between equations in “gather”?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2929/579) would be a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `multilined` is needed here. Consider the following code instead:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    Z &= \smash[b]{\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}} \tr \bigl\{ Q^{-1} \bigl[ (P_{k+1} + x_{k+1}^N     x_{k+1}^{N\prime}) - (P_{k+1,k}^N + x_{k+1}^N x_k^{N\prime}) A'\\[1ex]
      &\hspace{4em}  - A (P_{k,k+1}^N + x_k^N x_{k+1}^{N\prime}) + A(P_k^N + x_k^N     x_k^{N\prime})A' \bigr] \bigr\}\\[1ex]
    &=  \tr \bigl\{ Q^{-1} \bigl[ (P_{k+1} + x_{k+1}^N     x_{k+1}^{N\prime}) - (P_{k+1,k}^N + x_{k+1}^N x_k^{N\prime}) A' \\[1ex]
      &\hspace{4em}  - A (P_{k,k+1}^N + x_k^N x_{k+1}^{N\prime}) + A(P_k^N + x_k^N     x_k^{N\prime})A' \bigr] \bigr\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I inserted a `\smash` command to ignore the depth of the `\sum`, then manually added a `1ex` vertical space after each line. You can adjust the `1ex` to suit your needs, as well as the `4em` horizontal space for the trailing lines. Note the `[b]` option for `\smash`, which smashes the depth but not the height. (Thanks for the edit @egreg.)