# break long equation into lines (combine {align} and {multline})

Tags: equations, align

Is it possible to have aligned equations which one can split up if they are too long, but such that they are still aligned? I mean a single environment that combines align (equations remain aligned) and multline (if they are too long they may be split in a nice way)

If there is some math counterpart of the \hfill it will be great!

In the following the two vertical bars denote the default width of the math mode, and the minus signs denote empty space

the following is bad

```
|------------------------------------|

|aaa-=-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|

|---=-cccccccccccccccc-+-dddddddddddddddd
```

It must be somehow turned into

```
|------------------------------------|

|aaa-=-bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb|

|----=-cccccccccccccccc--------------|

|------------------+-dddddddddddddddd|
```

that is the second line when broken its other part must be

1. set in the third line but pushed to the right end and
2. that end is the farthest end of all lines (on the left) and
3. the equal signs are still aligned,

Comment: The answer: Yes. It would be better if you give a concrete example of what you have and what you want to achieve. Otherwise the question is too generic.

Comment: I guess `split` does what you want.

Comment: @Werner I editied the post so  I hope it is better now!

Comment: This is essentially the same as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/312487 using `multlined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
aaa & = bbbbbbbb           \\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
        cccccccccccccccc    \\
        + dddddddddddddddd
        \end{multlined}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

and one more example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
aaa & = bbbbbbbb           \\
    & \begin{multlined}[b][0.35\linewidth]
        = cccccccccccccccc    \\
        + dddddddddddddddd
        \end{multlined}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines show borders of text)

Answer (score 1):

I think the first form, using a fixed indent such as `\qquad` is most common, but the second form, using `multlined` is closest to what you ask for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

with qquad
\begin{align*}
  aaa&=bbb\\
     &=cccc\\
     &\qquad + ddddd
\end{align*}

with multlined
\begin{align*}
  aaa&=bbb\\
   &=\begin{multlined}[t]
      ccc\\
      {}+ ddd
     \end{multlined}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Physor as you see code in comments doesn't display well. _every_ question really should have a complete test document as in this answer that shows the problem, but I'll add your code and see what it does.....

Comment: @Physor impossible to say anything about that it has undefined commands and so produces no output. Please edit your question to add a usable test and I'll have a look.

Comment: I'm sorry it depends on other commands that are defined by me, so it want work if you try it

Comment: I'll edit my question later and I let you know, thanks a lot! and I'm sorry for any trouble

Comment: @Physor I can't run it but I would guess `V_\tx{eff}^{ll'}` is in error and should be `V_{\tx{eff}^{ll'}}`

Comment: As I mentioned, the code I provided relies heavily one predefined commands, so it will not work by any one else. It was my mistake forgeting that. But the multilined doesn't push the splitted part to the right end, it can still end before any sufficiently long line (which is not splitted)

Comment: @Physor sure but an unbraced subscript is almost always wrong (and that one gave an error if i defined all the undefined commands to work like `\log` (oh I guess `\tx` may have been short for `\text` which would sort of work)  yes multlined only works locally to work within its own space it can not see the total display. Personally I'd use `\qquad`