# How to write many equations(leftsided) with labels

Tags: align, labels

im working on my thesis and i have a major problem. I want to write down many equations with labels, bc i need the labels for references to explain those equations. Neither flalgin works with my texskill or gather.
So now im writing you guys for help, im totall frustrated.
This is my code

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Minimiere:} 
\begin{flalign} 
Z=c_{max}  \\
\label{eins}
%\intertext{unter den Nebenbedingungen} \nonumber
\textbf{unter der Nebenbedingungen} \nonumber 
\hat{c}_{r,m,i}\leq c_{j,n,i} + \Omega\cdot\chi_{r,m,j,n}-\Omega ;\ \ \forall({r,m,i,j,n})\\\label{zwei}
\hat{c}_{r,m,i}\geq c_{j,n,i} - \Omega\cdot\chi_{r,m,j,n}-\Omega;\ \ \forall({r,m,i,j,n}) \\ 
\label{drei}
\end{flalign}


Die Zielfunktion in Gleichung \eqref{eq:eins} soll die Produktionsdauer des Programms(schedule) minimieren, welches der Fertigstellungszeit des letzten zu bearbeitenden Sublots im System entspricht.Die Bedingungen in Gleichung \eqref{eq:zwei} und \eqref{eq:drei} sagen beide aus

\end{document}
```

Why those the error occur that label eins will be lost ? My Plan is to build a gather or align equation environment like this:[image: Equations]

Can you help me guys?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The example code has several useless packages for the problem. Next time try and minimize it.

Comment: [Crosspost](http://golatex.de/referenzieren-von-formeln-t18368.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code. One is that you need to use `\label` before `\\`. The second is that if you want to reference your equations by `\ref{eq:equationname}` then you have to label them using `\label{eq:equationname}`. The thing that goes inside the `\label` should be identical to the thing that goes in the `\ref`. Last, the commented out lines would cause a problem. The correct solution would be to say `\intertext{blah blah blah}` without using `\nonumber`. If you do want to use `\nonumber`, there should not be a label on the same line. Trying to use `\nonumber` and `\label` on the same line will cause `Error: label "labelname" will be lost`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Minimiere:}
\begin{flalign}
\label{eq:eins}Z&=c_{max}
\end{flalign}
\textbf{unter den Nebenbedingungen}
\begin{flalign}
\hat{c}_{r,m,i}\leq c_{j,n,i} + \Omega\cdot\chi_{r,m,j,n}-\Omega ;\ \ \forall({r,m,i,j,n})\label{eq:zwei}\\
\hat{c}_{r,m,i}\geq c_{j,n,i} - \Omega\cdot\chi_{r,m,j,n}-\Omega;\ \ \forall({r,m,i,j,n}) \label{eq:drei}
\end{flalign}


Die Zielfunktion in Gleichung \eqref{eq:eins} soll die Produktionsdauer des Programms(schedule) minimieren, welches der Fertigstellungszeit des letzten zu bearbeitenden Sublots im System entspricht.Die Bedingungen in Gleichung \eqref{eq:zwei} und \eqref{eq:drei} sagen beide aus

\end{document}
```

Comment: hey thanks for helping me out. The Packages i got are from the institute where i am writing my thesis, they gave me those template. Can you tell me whats useless please?

Comment: thank you hood chatam! but now its not leftsided? and the intertext is not thick? how can i change that

Comment: Edited.  It's not really possible for me to tell which of the packages you have loaded are useless from this little piece of your code.

Comment: my code is too long for hat comment window here... idk where to post it

Comment: thanks for editing! you are really nice ;) but minimiere and the first equation are still centerd and not on the left...

Comment: Edited again...

Comment: For the first, single equation, I'd use `equation` instead of `flalign`. And `\usepackage{parskip}` might be a better idea than `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`. (+1 though).

Comment: thanks both of you ! how can i change the vertical space between the equations? and why is parskip better than parindent?

Comment: @MiloLi With just `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` there will be no good way to tell where one paragraph ends and the next one begins. The `parskip` package also sets zero parindent, but in addition increases the vertical space between paragraphs (`\parskip`) and, I think, does some other small adjustments. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2929/586 for some methods to increase line spacing in multi-line equations, if that was what you meant. The question is about `gather`, but the same applies for `flalign` I believe.