# Control of spacing between equation lines when using split

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I am using [this LaTex template](http://thesis.gmu.edu/documents/GMU%20MS%20Thesis%20Template.zip) (see **gmuthesis.sty** and **GMU_thesis_template.tex** in the linked zip file) to generate a thesis. It has some long equations in it. When I render the below equation in the context of the template, I get picture A. When I render it in a barebones document having just the equation, I get picture B. I would like my equations to render like picture B. What setting is controlling the spacing between lines, and how should I change it?

**Equation**

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\frac{100}{2} = \frac{\begin{split}&\text{DG:SG:Granule } + \text{DG:SG:Total Molecular } + \text{DG:SG:MOLAX } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:Outer Molecular } + \text{DG:SG:HICAP } + \text{DG:SG:Axo-Axonic } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:HIPP } + \text{DG:SG:Aspiny Hilar } + \text{DG:SG:Basket-PV } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:Basket-CCK } + \text{DG:SG:Non-Ivy / NGF }\end{split}}{\begin{split}&\text{DG:SG:Total Molecular } + \text{DG:SG:MOLAX } + \text{DG:SG:Outer Molecular } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:HICAP } + \text{DG:SG:Axo-Axonic } + \text{DG:SG:HIPP } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:Aspiny Hilar } + \text{DG:SG:Basket-PV } + \text{DG:SG:Basket-CCK } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:Non-Ivy / NGF }\end{split}}\]
\end{document}
```

**Picture A**
[image]

**Picture B**
[image]

Comment: Could you please post a link to the mentioned template?

Comment: @karlkoeller Sorry about that, it's now linked

Comment: Also, the code you've posted is not compilable...

Comment: Also, the code you've posted doesn't correspond to the images; what should be the final look?

Comment: I can't get the code to compile. Can I suggest you define the denominator as one term (D for illustration) and the numerator as another (say N) and then express the fraction in those terms. It will not only be easier to read, it will look more attractive. Also, have you used the `align` environment?

Comment: @Mico My apologies for the confusion. I had truncated the top of the image.

Comment: @JasonWhyte The images now correspond to the code and the code now compiles. Thanks to all for your help!  JasonWhyte, I'm not quite sure what you mean by defining the numerator and denominator as one term. Don't they need to be multiple terms in order to be split?

Comment: My comment related to display. Even if you can make the fraction you want to make, there might be better (more readable) ways of communicating a mathematical idea than using split. I'll post something that would be an alternative, rather than strictly a solution.

Comment: maybe it's intentional, but the space before (most) pluses is wider than the space after.  this is caused by the space at the end of the `\text{xxx }` elements.  in math mode, with something on either side of a plus, the spacing is symmetrical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by providing an extra argument to `\\`; I replaced each `\\` with `\\[-20pt]`. More info about adjusting line spacing in this way can be found [here](http://www.personal.ceu.hu/tex/breaking.htm). I tried several other things as well:

- adjusting `jot`: `\setlength{\jot}{2pt}`. I found that if I set the `jot` size to large values I could INCREASE the spacing between lines, but I wanted to decrease them. Setting `jot` below a certain limit had no further effect; `2pt` did nothing more than `5pt`, for instance.
- adjusting `baselineskip`; no effect
- adjusting `baselinestretch`; no effect

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1580/increase-spacing-in-split-environment) is a good description of `jot`.

From [this description](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex/baselineskip.html) of `baselineskip`, it looks like this was somehow the problem. If anyone has any insight here, please comment!

Answer (score 0):

(second thought: with every term appearing in the denominator also appearing in the numerator, another choice of definition would make the content of the expression even clearer. I'll leave that for you to discuss with your advisor. ;] )

The maths doesn't have to do absolutely everything. For a (quick, imperfect) example:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The highly important matter of this thesis is summarised by the fraction
\begin{gather}
X = \frac{N}{D} \\
\noalign{\hbox{where the numerator}}
 \begin{aligned}
N &= \text{DG:SG:Granule } + \text{DG:SG:Total Molecular } + \text{DG:SG:MOLAX } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:Outer Molecular } + \text{DG:SG:HICAP } + \text{DG:SG:Axo-Axonic } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:HIPP } + \text{DG:SG:Aspiny Hilar } + \text{DG:SG:Basket-PV } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:Basket-CCK } + \text{DG:SG:Non-Ivy / NGF },
\end{aligned}  \notag \\
\noalign{\hbox{consists of the top terms and the denominator}}
\begin{aligned}
D &=\text{DG:SG:Total Molecular } + \text{DG:SG:MOLAX } + \text{DG:SG:Outer Molecular } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:HICAP } + \text{DG:SG:Axo-Axonic } + \text{DG:SG:HIPP } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:Aspiny Hilar } + \text{DG:SG:Basket-PV } + \text{DG:SG:Basket-CCK } +\\
& \text{DG:SG:Non-Ivy / NGF } .
\end{aligned} \notag \\
\noalign{\hbox{contains more bottom-related terms that are less granular in nature..}} \notag
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image: a quick way of communicating the content of a complicated fraction]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `array` instead of `split`:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tv}[1]{% text variable
  \textnormal{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\[
\frac{100}{2} =
\frac{
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \tv{DG:SG:Granule} + \tv{DG:SG:Total Molecular} + \tv{DG:SG:MOLAX} + {} \\
  \tv{DG:SG:Outer Molecular} + \tv{DG:SG:HICAP} + \tv{DG:SG:Axo-Axonic} + {} \\
  \tv{DG:SG:HIPP} + \tv{DG:SG:Aspiny Hilar} + \tv{DG:SG:Basket-PV} + {} \\
  \tv{DG:SG:Basket-CCK} + \tv{DG:SG:Non-Ivy} / \tv{NGF}
  \end{array}
}{
  \begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
  \tv{DG:SG:Total Molecular} + \tv{DG:SG:MOLAX} + \tv{DG:SG:Outer Molecular} + {}\\
  \tv{DG:SG:HICAP} + \tv{DG:SG:Axo-Axonic} + \tv{DG:SG:HIPP} + {} \\
  \tv{DG:SG:Aspiny Hilar} + \tv{DG:SG:Basket-PV} + \tv{DG:SG:Basket-CCK} + {}\\
  \tv{DG:SG:Non-Ivy} / \tv{NGF}
  \end{array}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]