# How to vertically align each comma in the following 2 identical sequences?

Tags: amsmath, align

The following output seems to be difficult to look up an item in the upper sequence with its corresponding item in the lower sequence as the commas are not vertically aligned.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax
\begin{align*}
\{a_n\}
&=
\{1^2, 1^2 +2^2, 1^2 +2^2 +3^2, 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2, \dotsc\}\\
&=
\{1, 5, 14, 30, \dotsc\}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I want to align each comma in the upper and lower sequence. How to do it elegantly (that consumes less keystrokes)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few ideas with `alignedat` (since this is only one formula I am using `equation`) and one with  `array` for centered aligning which otherwise would need more work to be able to be usable in one of the `*align*` environments.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{5}
\{a_n\} &= \{1^2 &&, 1^2 +2^2 &&, 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 &&, 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2 &&, \dotsc\} \\
        &= \{1   &&, 5        &&, 14            &&, 30                 &&, \dotsc\}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\renewcommand*\c{,{}}%
\begin{alignedat}{5}
\{a_n\} &= \{1^2 \c && 1^2 +2^2 \c && 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 \c && 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2 \c & \dotsc\} \\
        &= \{1   \c && 5        \c && 14            \c && 30                 \c & \dotsc\}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
\renewcommand*\c{,{}}%
\begin{alignedat}{6}
\{a_n\} &= \{& 1^2 \c && 1^2 +2^2 \c && 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 \c && 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2 \c && \dotsc\} \\
        &= \{& 1   \c && 5        \c && 14            \c && 30                 \c && \dotsc\}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{@{}r@{} *4{c@{,{}}} l@{}}
     \{a_n\} = \{ & 1^2 & 1^2 +2^2 & 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 & 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2 & \dotsc\} \\[\jot]
             = \{ & 1   & 5        & 14            & 30                 & \dotsc\}
  \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: What is `\jot`?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot The space (it’s a `\dimen`) between math-mode lines. It is defined by LaTeX and set to `3pt`. For reference, see [Increase spacing in split environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1580).

Answer (score 14):

I understand that this does not answer your question in the strict sense, but in my opinion the output is clearer:

> [image: set]

```
\documentclass[border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
     \{a_n\} = \{\overbrace{1^2}^1,
                 \overbrace{1^2+2^2}^5,
                 \overbrace{1^2 +2^2 +3^2}^{14},
                 \overbrace{1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2}^{30},\dotsc \}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A nice idea and make the code tidier.

Comment: You could probably also do it with `\underbrace`, making the output closer to what th OP intended. On the other hand this looks much better than any of the "valid" solutions

Answer (score 7):

A contest? `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\alignedset}[2][l]{%
  \vcenter{
    \everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}
    \m@th\let\\\@tabularcr\openup1\jot
    \ialign{\hfil$##$&${}##{}$\hfil&&
            \if#1l\hfilneg\fi\hfil
            $##{}$%
            \if#1r\hfilneg\fi\hfil
            \cr#2\crcr}
    }%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\alignedset{
  \{a_n\} &= \{ & 1^2, & 1^2+2^2, & 1^2+2^2+3^2, & 1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2, & \dotsc \} \\
          &= \{ & 1,   & 5,       & 14,          & 30,              & \dotsc\}
}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\alignedset[c]{
  \{a_n\} &= \{ & 1^2, & 1^2+2^2, & 1^2+2^2+3^2, & 1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2, & \dotsc \} \\
          &= \{ & 1,   & 5,       & 14,          & 30,              & \dotsc\}
}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\alignedset[r]{
  \{a_n\} &= \{ & 1^2, & 1^2+2^2, & 1^2+2^2+3^2, & 1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2, & \dotsc \} \\
          &= \{ & 1,   & 5,       & 14,          & 30,              & \dotsc\}
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: quasi pure `Plain TeX` were it not for `\let\\\@tabularcr`, are you abandoning `LaTeX3` ? :)

Comment: @jfbu Elegant syntax calls for low level methods. `;-)`

Answer (score 4):

Using the (experimental) `tabstackengine` package given at [Measuring align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142406/measuring-align/142608#142608)

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\tabbedstackunder{%
\{a_n\}
&=
\{1^2&, 1^2 +2^2&, 1^2 +2^2 +3^2&, 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2&, \dotsc\}%
}{%
&=
\{1&, 5&, 14&, 30&, \dotsc\}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To put all 3 alignment choices into a single macro, with the inter-equation gap set to 10pt, and the inter-line gap set to 3pt:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\setstackgap{S}{10pt}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\Shortstack{
\tabbedstackunder[3pt]{%
\{a_n\}
&=
\{1^2&, 1^2 +2^2&, 1^2 +2^2 +3^2&, 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2&,& \dotsc\}%
}{%
&=\{1&, 5&, 14&, 30&,& \dotsc\}}
\\
\renewcommand\stackalignment{c}
\tabbedstackunder[3pt]{%
\{a_n\}
&=&
\{&1^2&,& 1^2 +2^2&,& 1^2 +2^2 +3^2&,& 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2&,& \dotsc\}%
}{%
&=&\{&1&,& 5&,& 14&,& 30&,& \dotsc\}}
\\
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\tabbedstackunder[3pt]{%
\{a_n\}
=&
\{&1^2,& 1^2 +2^2,& 1^2 +2^2 +3^2,& 1^2 +2^2 +3^2 +4^2,& \dotsc\}%
}{%
=&\{&1,& 5,& 14,& 30,& \dotsc\}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DonutE.Knot Sorry, I had to head out after posting.  Correction applied.